# To implement conversion chain without being repetitive?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Out of context paraphrase: What is the best practice to implement conversions among several "related" structures/classes statically (that is, no `virtual`)?

---

The context: I have several structures that are used to access arrays which deal with ownership and stride, etc.
If they were to be represented in an inheritance diagram, I'd have something like this:

```
    array_view / const (fake pointers)
       ^
       |
    array_ref / const
       ^
       |
     array
```

These structures have no actual inheritance whatsoever as they have completely different data members.

But logically the conversion relations are:

1. `array` can be converted to `array_ref`
2. `array_ref` can be converted to `array_view`
3. `array_{ref, view}` can be converted to their `const` counterparts
4. (Implied) `array` can be converted to `array_view` (via `array_ref`)
5. (Implied) `array` can be converted to `const_array_view`, for example

---

Current solution: conversion operators are implemented up to each one's "parent level", (that is, `array` to `array_ref`, `array_ref` to `array_view`) and to convert add `const` (that is, `array_view` to `const_array_view`, for instance).

But then to pass `array` to a function that expects `const_array_view`, one needs two `static_cast`s. This makes lengthy and ugly code as all these structures are templates, and the code lines just blow up.

A simple brute force "improvement" would be implementing all possible conversion as implicit conversions. But I'm wondering if there's any common practice that makes such conversions easier (read: without casts) introducing too much maintenance trouble or runtime penalty.

Comment: "What is the best practice to implement conversions among several "related" structures/classes statically (that is, no virtual)?" - So, both opinions and open solutions in one go?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ugh, this is complicated... I realize should not say "best", especially on SO. But on the other hand, it can be _somewhat_ quantified (by, say code duplication) if a concrete solution is given. Quite sadly, "best" sounds as good/bad as "most maintainable" to me. In other words, it's kind of opinion based but it still makes a constructive question IMO.

Comment: It was supposed to be a trigger.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh yeah. Appreciated!